# Get port of the incoming tcp connection

Tags: sockets, networking, c#-4.0, network-programming, nat

how could I get the port of the client that is connecting to the c# application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` object, Type-cast its `RemoteEndPoint` property to an `IPEndPoint` and then read its `Port` property.

Answer (score 0):

To listen on a socket, don't you need to *know* the port number first?

Comment: sure but I need the client port for NAT punchtrough a server. I don't need the port where the client program is binded but the one of the connection aasigned by the router

Comment: Then I'd suggest you go to http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfcsearch.html and search for `NAT` and/or `Network Address Translation`. And the work through the RFCs. Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal